# When do I solve a quadratic expression by either factorising, completing the square or use the quadratic formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What are the rules and conditions as to which method I should use. I know how to use them, just not when I should.

Comment: You can't solve a quadratic expression only a quadratic equation. As for which method? Ask yourself questions like how many terms are there? Which terms? Is the coefficient of $x $ greater than one? Is the coefficient of  $x $ even.  If there are only 2 terms is one of them the $x $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely a matter of taste.  Most people try factoring first.  If the quadratic doesn't factor or is difficult to factor, many people will try the quadratic formula next, although completing the square is perfectly fine.  Both completing the square and the quadratic formula work for every quadratic equation.

Comment: In fact, completing the square may be viewed simply as a way to \emph{derive} the quadratic formula. It has the advantage that it doesn't require remembering any formulas, but at the cost of requring a few additional algebraic manipulations. Thus completing the square is usually favored over the quadratic formula by people who, like me, aren't good at learning things by heart.

Comment: But are there any cases of these two methods yielding different results for the same equation? and is the only way to know that factorising is possible is if the discriminant indicates that surds will turn into integers?

Comment: No, completing the square will always give the same result as the quadratic formula.  In fact, the quadratic formula is derived by applying the completing the square method to the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. In essence, the quadratic formula does completing the square for you.  As far as when a quadratic will factor, the discriminant is the most accurate way.  Beyond that its mostly by inspection, and trial and error.

Comment: @Heath Baron-Morgan The answer to your question really depends upon your ultimate goal. For example if you consider only integers then there are no solutions to $x^2-2=0 $ because it cannot be factored over the integers. The reals have no trouble in this respect. So I propose a different question. Why and when does factoring fail? What can be done about it?